# How to calculate number of days and date range in jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery Datepicker. I am able to calculate the number of days between two date selected but I need to be able to select a date range(selected 'fromdate' to become 'minim' for 'todate' and selected 'todate' to become 'maxim' for 'fromdate').
I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
        var diff = 1;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = diff + Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
        }
        $('.calculated').val(diff);
        $('.minim').val(d1)
    }
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: 'minim'
});
$('.todate').datepicker({ 
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: 'fromdate'
});
$('.fromdate,.todate').change(selector)
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXMv6/)?

Comment: Yes, with a little twist. But now I think I will manage.

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic - Yes, working! Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem. what was the problem first time?

Comment: I was able to calculate number of days OR to restrict date range so the user will have to select a valid period of time (any period starting with today and ending at a day in the future). With your sample I am able to do both things in the same time (until nou I used something to check the form and to have number of days >= 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bojan Kovacevic I managed to solve my problem. It is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
        $('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate",d2); //new line           
        $('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate",d1); // new line
        var diff = 1;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = diff + Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000);
        }
        $('.calculated').val(diff);
        $('.minim').val(d1)
    }    
$(".fromdate").datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
});
$('.todate').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: ($(".fromdate").is(":visible") && $(".todate").html() != ""? $('.todate').datepicker('getDate'): 'null'), // new line
});
$('.fromdate,.todate').change(selector)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BXMv6/3/) link this will help you to calculate the number of days between two date selected,and to be able to select a date range.

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var minValue = $(this).val();
    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
    $('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
    calculate();
});
$('.todate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var maxValue = $(this).val();
    maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
    $('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
    calculate();
});
```

I hope this will help you.